# Fixing unexpected GET request in service unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-services

In my unit test for a service, I'm testing a GET request. I'm getting the following error, even when I explicitly state `$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/example').respond(200, {});`.

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/another/example
Expected GET /api/example
```

**Unit test**

```
 describe('MyService', function() {
    var MyService,
        $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('example'));

    beforeEach(function() {
      inject(function(_MyService_, _$httpBackend_) {
        MyService = _MyService_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/example').respond(200, {});
      });
    })

    describe('#get', function() {
      beforeEach(function() {

        // this is what i want to test
        $httpBackend
          .expectGET('/api/another/example')
          .respond(200, {});

      });

      it('should send a get request', function() {
        MyService.get();

        $httpBackend.flush();
      });
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the content of your `MyService.get()` function, but I'll go ahead and assume it's calling `GET /api/another/example`.

If I remember correctly, you have to serve your expected requests on `$httpBackend` in the order you list them.

Assuming both beforeEach segments get triggered you would have to set off a `GET` request against `/api/example` before you can access `GET /api/another/example`.